# R: Ordering and transforming irregular time strings

Tags: r, time, time-series

I have a similar problem to the following question on transforming irregular time strings. Where I have a time series of a character class which I would like to order.

[R: transform irregular time strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711927/r-transform-irregular-time-strings)

Rather than commas, my milliseconds are in separated by a ʻ.ʻ. However, when I try to apply the gsub step, all my data is replaced with semi-colons.

> head(time, n=5)

[1] "05:48:59.306" "05:48:56.246" "05:48:53.214" "05:48:52.662" "05:48:50.203"

> time.new <- gsub(".", ":", time)
>
> head(time.new, n=10)

[1] "::::::::::::" "::::::::::::" "::::::::::::" "::::::::::::" "::::::::::::"

If I could get through this step, I would in theory calculate decimal minutes as another column and then order based on the decimal minutes.  What am I missing with the gsub part?  :p

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use two `\` before `.` in `gsub()`.

```
gsub("\\.", ":", time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fixed=TRUE`:

```
gsub(".", ":", time,fixed=TRUE)
```

For example:

```
time <- c("05:48:59.306", "05:48:56.246" ,"05:48:53.214" ,"05:48:52.662", "05:48:50.203")
gsub(".", ":", time,fixed=TRUE)
"05:48:59:306" "05:48:56:246" "05:48:53:214" "05:48:52:662" "05:48:50:203"
```

Comment: The reasoning being of course that `.` refers to "any single character" in `regex`.